# Baidu map integration error in android 6 and above

Tags: baidu-map

I have implemented Baidu map in my application and it is working fine in android version below 6 but have problem with above android 6 versions.
I have implemented dynamic WRITE_SETTING permission for android 6. If user give permission to app then also Baidu MapView class not able to access it and it is crashing.
Error log as below

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: requires permission android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
at com.baidu.android.bbalbs.common.util.a.a(DeviceId.java:206)
at com.baidu.android.bbalbs.common.util.a.a(DeviceId.java:68)
at com.baidu.android.bbalbs.common.util.CommonParam.b(CommonParam.java:72)
at com.baidu.android.bbalbs.common.util.CommonParam.a(CommonParam.java:45)
at com.baidu.platform.comapi.c.c.p(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.platform.comapi.c.c.c(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.mapapi.a.b(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.mapapi.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.mapapi.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, due to different permission mechanism approach in Android 6 (as described in https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html). 
Solved asking write_settings permission in this way:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this ,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,1);
```

where "this" is an Activity containing method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] results) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (results.length > 0
                    && results[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //You had the permission
                } else {
                    // Permission denied!
                }
                return;
            }
            // With additional 'case' you can handle additional permission check
        }


    }}
```